# Which permissions / roles are required for item cloning?

Tags: security, role-management, item-clones

I have a user who needs the ability to clone items. The problem is that the clone options do not appear in the ribbon.

**Expected State**

[image: expected clone button]

**Actual State**

[image: missing clone button]

Which role do I need to assign the user to grant them the ability to clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally recommend avoiding cloning at all costs (in almost all cases). That said, the role you need is `sitecore\Sitecore Client Developing`. This role is quite permissive and will also grant the user other developer/admin tier functionality.

Consider this lightweight solution instead:

We can [define a custom role with a self documenting name](https://sitecore.marcelgruber.ca/posts/self-documenting-roles), with the sole purpose of granting access to cloning functionality in the ribbon. Let's name the role `Client Name && Item Cloning Ribbon && ALLOW READ`. Then, update the permissions on the items:

[image: add security permissions to items]

Then, we assign that role to the user (or to another role) so we can easily see that they have those permissions via the "Member Of" role list.

[image: member of new role]

Remember to also do the following (if applicable):

- Serialize / back up the role
- Serialize / back up the items in which the security permissions were changed on
- Incorporate these updates in your identity provider claims configuration